# Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null using JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am facing the error "Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null" while populating a list. Here is my code:

```
       function setTemplates(){
           $.ajax({
                    url:"GetTemplates.jsp",

                    success:function(result){
                        //alert("Result Returned:");
                        var myObj = result;
                        myObj= JSON.parse(myObj);
                        alert(myObj.details[0].text);
                        var count =0;
                        var div = document.querySelector("#templates");
                        frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
                        select = document.createElement('select');
                        select.setAttribute('id', 'selectedCodes');
                        select.setAttribute('multiple', '');
                        select.setAttribute("onchange", "GetSelectedCodes()")
                        //select.setAttribute("onchange", "SetWrapUpCode(this.value)")
                        select.setAttribute("class", "list-group checked-list-box");
                        select.setAttribute("size", "7")
                        select.setAttribute("style", "width:270px; clear:both; float:left")

                        for(var j=0; j<myObj.names.length; j++)
                        {
                            //alert(myObj.names[j].name)
                            select.options.add( new Option(myObj.names[j].name, myObj.names[j].name, true, true) );

                        }

                        frag.appendChild(select);
                        div.removeChild(div.childNodes[0]);
                        div.appendChild(frag);


                    }
                });
   }
```

here is my HTML Code:

```
  <div class="col-md-5">
        <h3>Templates</h3>
           <div class="well">
               <form id="templates">
               </form>
           </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my JSP code

```
 <%
 TemplateClient templates = new TemplateClient();
 JSONObject templateResponse = new JSONObject();
 templateResponse = templates.getResponse(); 
 out.print(templateResponse);
 out.flush();
 %>
```

I am using NetBeans for this. Please help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: please put your jsp or html code as well, because there may be issue regarding your dom element with id="templates" and pease also mention when you are calling this function ?

Comment: so this is getTemplates.jsp ?

Comment: Yes, it is. here is my complete code. I am calling the setTemplates function to populate dynamic multi-selected list in my HTML.

Comment: I am calling this function onload event in html

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null at query selector because your DOM is not prepare yet. try to replace your  `var div = document.querySelector("#templates");` line with
`var div = $(result).find('#templates');`

Comment: I have tried your solution but getting this error now. 
jquery.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {"details":[{"text":"Testing Queued messages"},{"text":"EF Testing campaign "},{"text":"New Offer\r\n40% flat off "}],"names":[{"name":"SMS Test"},{"name":"Testing template"},{"name":"Offer"}]}

Comment: so are you sure <form id="templates"> is in GetTemplates.jsp ? because your response is like json not jsp